# Android Studio combine 2 .aar into one

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

I have an Android Studio library project which depends on another library project.

The top project depends on code and resources from the second library project.

When using just the top library-project .aar in a client app, the resources from the second library project are not found.

So do we have to always use 2 .aar files instead of one in such a situation?

Comment: gradle transitive dependency should just be able to map from mainApp-> aar1 -> aar2 via dependencies listed in respective build gradle files.

sample proj build 1 & 2  :: https://github.com/googlecast/CastVideos-android/blob/master/build.gradle  :: https://github.com/googlecast/CastCompanionLibrary-android/blob/master/build.gradle

Comment: hi @Demonick I made a long explanation for combining aar in this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26020466/android-studio-generate-aar-with-dependency/48434752#48434752

Comment: @aldok Yes the process ended up being similar to that.